# jQuery select input type text where ID not equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the code listed below in order to restrict user input on all inputs whose type is `text`. Now I want to exclude all inputs whose ID is `allowall` from this restriction. How can I modify the code to allow this?

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: use .not selector. IT will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type=text]').not('#allowall').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You also may use `:not` selector, which should be faster, because of `!=` is jQuery selector and `:not` is css selector. Like this:

```
$('input[type=text]:not(#allowall)').keypress(function(e){
    /*stuff*/
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute does not equal selector

```
$(":text[id!='allowall']").keypress(function (e) {
  // do stuff with `<input type="text">` elements
  // that do not have `id` equal to `"allowall"`
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for id of textbox and exclude them regex test

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function (e) {

   if($(this).attr('id') == 'allowall')
     return true;

    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```